# How to upload an image to canvas using Vaadin?

Tags: java, canvas, components, vaadin

I currently have an upload function working using the Upload component from Vaadin, but I am unsure of how to draw the image result from the file upload into a canvas as I am new to Vaadin/Java. The image is able to be uploaded successfully, but the canvas won't appear. I need a canvas as I will use it to draw boxes on the image uploaded subsequently.

This is my code:

```
package com.vaadin.starter.beveragebuddy.backend;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.dependency.HtmlImport;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.H2;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.upload.Upload;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.upload.receivers.MultiFileMemoryBuffer;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import java.awt.Canvas;

public class MainLayout extends VerticalLayout {

    private Canvas canvas;

    public MainLayout() {
        H2 title = new H2("Image Annotation Tool");

        MultiFileMemoryBuffer buffer = new MultiFileMemoryBuffer();
        Upload upload = new Upload(buffer);

        upload.addSucceededListener(event -> {
//            Component component = createComponent(event.getMIMEType(),
//                    event.getFileName(),
//                    buffer.getInputStream(event.getFileName()));
//            showOutput(event.getFileName(), component, output);


        });
        add(upload);
    }

    public void Test() {
        Frame frame = new Frame("Testing");
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        frame.add(new ImageCanvas());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class ImageCanvas extends Canvas {

        private BufferedImage img;

        public ImageCanvas() {
            try {
                img = ImageIO.read(new File("upload"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return img == null ? new Dimension(1580, 800) : new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);
            if (img != null) {
                int x = (getWidth() - img.getWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - img.getHeight()) / 2;
                g.drawImage(img, x, y, this);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Which vaadin version is it?

Comment: @AndréSchild Version 10 :)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately AWT(desktop component) Canvas can not be used in Vaadin(web) application.
There are multiple ways to implement your idea:

- File upload to server, using `javax.imageio.ImageIO` on server side(as you half-done already) and then downloading it back to the client as an image resource, using `StreamResource` and `Image`
- Client-side html5 canvas manipulations using JavaScript.

  You need to define first what do you need to implement

Comment: You have nothing to do with Canvas and Frame, you need to call `BufferedImage.createGraphics()` and then draw whatever you want on it.

Answer (score 1):

Server JVMs typically run headless (that is, no display) and therefore can't create AWT Components. However, you can still use `BufferedImage` to paint: `BufferedImage` will work even in headless mode. You may need to tell JVM that there is no head so that JVM will not even attempt to try to connect to it, by using the JVM parameter `-Djava.awt.headless=true`.

To load the image into `BufferedImage` from `InputStream` and manipulate it and write it out:

```
final BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(inputStream);
final Graphics2D canvas = img.createGraphics();
// draw using canvas directly into the BufferedImage

// when you're done, write it to a temp file, or an in-memory output stream:
ImageIO.write(img, ...);
```

Then you can serve the generated png image file as a Vaadin Image, see https://vaadin.com/docs/v11/flow/advanced/tutorial-dynamic-content.html for more details.